# DNS Issue with active directory

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, controller

I Made Domain Controller in Virtual Machine and I configured all the setting that related with DNS And DHCP. In another server I have local website that running in Xampp Server etc.

I've added the IP of server that running the website on xampp in DNS of Active Directory (Virtual machine).  When I enter the name of site on Google on PC domain it cannot reach  the IP address with knowing that I've added the IP address on host of domain controller .

Comment: It is challenging to understand exactly what you have done.  More detail would help

Comment: look , i have a system in my company and the name should be example.example1.net but the dns dose not work because the period is the problem but when add any name without period its work .

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your question is that you have set up an Active Directory with internal DNS as per the requirements, and you have added the name of your website/web server to your internal DNS. However, when you attempt to find your web server externally, the name does not resolve. Is this correct?

In most cases smaller setups don't present their internal DNS zones to the Internet at large. Instead they would have so-called split DNS, where they run an internal DNS infrastructure as usual, but explicitly register public DNS records with an external service provider - usually their domain name registrar.

Comment: look , i have a system in my company and the name should be example.example1.net but the dns dose not work because the period is the problem but when add any name without period its work.